# How to break out of while loop within for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I need to cleanly break out of a while loop(null check) and go to the next iteration of the outer for loop.

I have tried putting

```
for(Product: product:ListofProducts){
 while(null!=product.getDate){
    if(product.getDate>specifiedDate){
        doOnething()
    }
    else{
        doAnotherThing()
    }
    continue;
}
```

if the product date is not null and it does onething() or anotherthing() , then I want to move onto the next iteration of the for loop

Comment: set product.getDate() to null

Comment: use the "break" command

Comment: you can label your for loop `nameofloop: for(Product: product:ListofProducts){..}
` and then `continue nameofloop; `

Comment: You are continuing the `while` loop in every case, is that desired? I don't really get the necessarity of a `while` loop in this case, anyway... Why do you use it?

Comment: You can use if instead of while, Is that the expectation is different?

Comment: If you want to move to the next iteration of your outer loop, regardless of whether doOnething() or doAnotherthing() was called, you definitely don't need that inner loop

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways.

You can `break` from the inner loop:

```
for(...) {
    while(...) {
       ... 
       if(condition) {
          break;
       }
       ...
    }
 }
```

This will leave the inner loop and the outer loop will continue.

Or you can label the outer loop, and use `continue` with the name. By default `continue` and `break` apply to the innermost loop, but using a name overrides that.

```
someName: for(...) {
    while(...) {
       ... 
       if(condition) {
          continue someName;
       }
       ...
    }
 }
```

Or, you can usually achieve it without `break` or `continue`:

```
for(...) {
    boolean done = false;
    while(... && !done) {
       ... 
       if(condition) {
          done = true;
       }
    }
 }
```

Some people advise avoiding `break` and `continue` for the same reason they advise avoiding `return` in the middle of a routine. Having more than one exit point for a routine is an opportunity for confusing the reader.

However, that can be mitigated by ensuring the routine is short. The problem is where your exit points get lost in long blocks of code.

Comment: I always find the adding of an extra variable just to avoid the use of `break` more confusing than the `break` itself.

Comment: @aSlug I find that the longer I program, the less often I find I need to do any of these -- but I can't quite put my finger on why that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Product: product:ListofProducts){
 boolean done = false;
 while(null!=product.getDate && !done){
    if(product.getDate>specifiedDate){
        doOnething();
        done = true;
    }
    else{
        doAnotherThing();
        done = true;
    }
    continue;
}
```

Comment: The breaking condition in your example is always fulfilled. You are either not entering the inner loop or leaving it right after the first iteration. Your answer replicates the flaw of the original code